# How can I tell which makefile the make command used?

Tags: makefile

I'm working on a project which requires using `make`.

From the command like I run either `make Release` or `make Debug`.

However, there is not a `makefile` in the directory in which I run the `make` command.

How can I tell which `makefile` the `make` command is using?

Comment: Which make are you using? GNU make? System V make? BSD make? What's your operating system?

Comment: I'm using GNU Make 3.8.1.

Comment: There is no such thing as GNU make 3.8.1.  I assume you mean GNU make 3.81.  This is a very old version but it does support the `MAKEFILE_LIST` variable recommended by Jens below; that's your best bet IMO.  If you want to know how make finds a makefile, see https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Makefile-Names.html

Comment: You're correct.  I'm using GNU Make 3.81.

Comment: I am also curious about this because in coq there is a `CoqMakefile` that is auto generated by the `coq_makefile` command. So I am curious, when you run `make` how does it know which file to run? ref: https://coq.inria.fr/refman/practical-tools/utilities.html and https://makefiletutorial.com/

Answer (score 1):

In GNU make you can use the make variable `MAKEFILE_LIST` to inspect which makefile(s) were read; yes, there can be more than one due to multiple `-f` options and include directives.

If you need the name of the last read makefile, use `$(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST))`.

See also the [GNU make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#index-MAKEFILE_005fLIST-_0028list-of-parsed-makefiles_0029).

Comment: I am also curious about this because in coq there is a `CoqMakefile` that is auto generated by the `coq_makefile` command. So I am curious, when you run `make` how does it know which file to run? ref: https://coq.inria.fr/refman/practical-tools/utilities.html and https://makefiletutorial.com/

Answer (score 0):

GNU make has a debug option. If you use `-d`, make will print all debugging output.
The debug level can be changed with `--debug[=FLAGS]`.

`--debug=v` should show you which makefiles were parsed.

[GNU make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Options-Summary):

> v (verbose):
>   A level above ‘basic’; includes messages about which makefiles were parsed, prerequisites that did not need to be rebuilt, etc. This option also enables ‘basic’ messages.

See the man page for additional information.

Comment: I am also curious about this because in coq there is a `CoqMakefile` that is auto generated by the `coq_makefile` command. So I am curious, when you run `make` how does it know which file to run? ref: https://coq.inria.fr/refman/practical-tools/utilities.html and https://makefiletutorial.com/

Answer (score 0):

By default, when make looks for the makefile, it tries the following names, in order:
GNUmakefile,
makefile,
Makefile.
so try looking for files with that name.

If you want to use a nonstandard name for your makefile, you can specify the makefile name with the ‘-f’ or ‘--file’ option. The arguments ‘-f name’ or ‘--file=name’ tell make to read the file name as the makefile.